# Reading a file from an exported folder

Tags: c++

I have file (let's call it "file.txt") which is in a folder `/folder/where/the/file/is`.
And this folder has been exported to `$FOLDER`, such as if I do :

`echo $FOLDER`, I got : `folder/where/the/file/is`

Now, I want to test if the file exists or not.

So, I tried

```
  ifstream ifile(Name_finput);

  if(!ifile.good()){  
  cout << "File doesn't exist !" << endl;
  return;
  }
```

This works if `Name_finput = "/folder/where/the/file/is/file.txt"`, but not if `Name_finput=$FOLDER/file.txt`

Is there a way for it to work by keeping the form `$FOLDER/file.txt` ?
It seems that the compiler doesn't interpret `$FOLDER` as `/folder/where/the/file/is`.

Comment: `$FOLDER` is not a thing in C++. What you need is `std::getenv()`.

Comment: Lookup for `getenv()`.

Answer (score 0):

`$FOLDER` is not valid C++ code. In order to access the environment variables, you need to use `std::getenv()`. Here's how your code should look:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

int main() {

    std::ifstream ifile;

    if (const char* e = std::getenv("FOLDER")) {

        ifile.open(std::string(e) + std::string("/file.txt"));

        if (!ifile.is_open()) {

            std::cout << "File doesn't exist !" << std::endl;

        } else {

            // Do-stuff with the file

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```